# No data is showing in combobox

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am trying show some data from a database to a combobox based on another combobox selection with this code:

```
  private void metroComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel8.Text);
           DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(metroLabel9.Text);
           // Make sql readable
           string sql = 
             @"Select [LedId],[LedName] from [Ledger] where Date >= @prmStartDate and Date <= @prmEndDate";

           // wrap IDisposable (SqlCommand) into using
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate;
               con.Close();
               SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               da.Fill(dt);
               VoucherLedgerName_combo.DisplayMember = "LedName";
               VoucherLedgerName_combo.ValueMember = "LedId";
               VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt.Tables["Ledger"];
           }
        }
        catch(Exception exe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
}
```

But i am getting nothing in the second combobox, and I am sure that there is data in the database table Ledger. Can any one please help me to find the issue?

Comment: Is your query executes fine as you expected? is the datatable is populated ?

Comment: Are you receiving the data for the second combo-box?

Comment: @ un-lucky,@FDavidov how can i know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your SQL statement as below(Date is reserved keyword)

```
string sql = 
         @"Select [LedId],[LedName] from [Ledger] where [Date] >= @prmStartDate and [Date] <= @prmEndDate";
```

You need to give table name when you fill dataset since you are using the name when you set data source

```
da.Fill(dt, "Ledger");
```

or set the data source as below

```
VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Ledger"] = "--Select All--";
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change from

```
da.Fill(dt);
VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt.Tables["Ledger"];
```

to

```
da.Fill(dt, "Ledger");
VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt.Tables["Ledger"].DefaultView;
```

else

```
VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

or

```
VoucherLedgerName_combo.DataSource = dt;
```